# How to build a translation corpus for python NLTK?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, corpus

I've been working with Python's NTLK for doing general language parsing and recently I would like to create a corpus specifically for translations.  I've been unable to understand the corpus options and structures used by NTLK for translations.

There is a lot of [material on how to read or use corpus resources](http://www.nltk.org/howto/corpus.html), but I'm unable to find anything in detail on creating a translation style corpus.  I understand from browsing the corpus references that there are a variety of styles and types, however I can't seem to find any translation specific corpus examples or documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For translation like datasets, NLTK can read corpora of word-aligned sentences using the [AlignedCorpusReader](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/aligned.html). The files must have the following format:

```
first source sentence
first target sentence 
first alignment
second source sentence
second target sentence
second alignment
```

This means that tokens are assumed to be separated by whitespace and sentences begin on separate lines. For instance suppose you have a directory structure like the following:

```
reader.py
data/en-es.txt
data/en-pt.txt
```

where the content of the files are:

```
# en-es.txt
This is an example
Esto es un ejemplo
0-0 1-1 2-2 3-3
```

and

```
# en-pt.txt
This is an example
Esto é um exemplo
0-0 1-1 2-2 3-3
```

You could load this toy example using the following script:

```
# reader.py    
from nltk.corpus.reader.aligned import AlignedCorpusReader

reader = AlignedCorpusReader('./data', '.*', '.txt', encoding='utf-8')

for sentence in reader.aligned_sents():
    print(sentence.words)
    print(sentence.mots)
    print(sentence.alignment)
```

**Output**

```
['This', 'is', 'an', 'example']
['Esto', 'es', 'un', 'ejemplo']
0-0 1-1 2-2 3-3
['This', 'is', 'an', 'example']
['Esto', 'é', 'um', 'exemplo']
0-0 1-1 2-2 3-3
```

The line `reader = AlignedCorpusReader('./data', '.*', '.txt', encoding='utf-8')` creates an instance of the `AlignedCorpusReader` that reads all files that end with `'.txt'` in the './data' directory. It also specifies that the encoding of the files is `'utf-8'`. Other parameters of the `AlignedCorpusReader` are  `word_tokenizer` and `sent_tokenizer`, `word_tokenizer` is set to `WhitespaceTokenizer()` and `sent_tokenizer` is set to `RegexpTokenizer('\n', gaps=True)`.

More information can be found in the documentation ([1](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.translate.html) and [2](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/aligned.html)).

Comment: Thanks.  As a programmer trying to help someone build a model for an uncommon language this is a good start for me to learn the jargon and techniques.